# How do I add rotational motors in BGE

Tags: game-engine

Unlike Cycles Render mode, BGE has no Rigid Body Constraints in the physics panel. I can add hinges/etc but no physical motor force to move them. I believe the logic blocks allow you to, however it only allows translational motor servo for location OR simple motion where it rotates buuut teleports instead of passing coordinates in between. (edit, no it doesn't teleport)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple way is to use the "angular velocity" field of the simple motion brick. But that doesn't give you any angular-speed ramp-up the way things in the normal world work.

Another way is to use torques, and to set the rotational damping in the physics really really high. This gives you the required ramp up, but also affects how the object responds to impacts.

The normal solution I use is to code it. This can either be done by directly applying torques to the object (ie the KX_GameObject.applyTorque() function), or it can be done by creating a constraint and setting the various parameters. As you are making a game, I highly suggest learning python - it really will make things significantly easier.

Comment: The "angular velocity" route lets gravity etc affect it while on...do you mean the speed applied is constant? That too is correct.....And any speed inputed is fed in as more velocity into the cube, we know it adds up too because gravity adds to the velocity...

Comment: The angular speed is set as a constant when using the angular velocity field. So you can't get it to start out slow and speed up (spinning). But it does not affect linear velocity.

Comment: If I place a heavy object over my test cube, and hold down a button that makes it rotate to the edge of the floor plane, it doesn't ratate too fast and slows rotation at certain points from the above cube, meaning its rotation and translation velocity can intake/lose inertia.........It would have to purposely subtract a calculated amount to make sure its own force doesn't add to the cube's velocity, who would do that to BGE??

Comment: Oh, the rotational speed cannot go any higher. I tried dropping a heavy box on a rectangle that I had slowly rotating off a plane by holding A down, and it didn't intake as much velocity as it does when not holding A down.

Comment: It did however intake some. Using Torque seems to intake as much as when not holding down A.